# How to detect large size of html over a certain buffer size and close the current window

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asp-classic

I would like to close the current window if the size of the html buffer size is over a certain limit like > 2 to 5 megabytes. Is there a way to do this in html once the buffer or response.write gets too big?  Is there a way to detect the buffer size in javascript or html?

I want to tell the user that the size is simply too big, and ask them to select a different filter.  Either that or wait until after working hours to perform large query and html dump.

Comment: Any reason about why this can't be done in the server side?

Comment: If you are creating large HTML documents on your server, then you should implement the size limitations on the server.  If you are building large HTML documents via ajax calls and dynamically generated content, then you can keep track of how much content you've put in the page and stop when some size limit that you care about is reached.

Comment: Before the client's computer hangs, I'd like to be able to stop the flood of data especially if a newer programmer is involved.  Instead of having the client wait all day, resetting iis etc...

Comment: What type of data are you sending to the user?  I ask because these scenarios typically involve databases and are great candidates for paging...

Answer (score 1):

If you do this at the client side, then it's too late. The page is already created, and sent to the browser.

You should detect this where it's easy, i.e. on the server side when you fetch the data (wherever you do that from), and not create the HTML output in the first place.

I would suggest that you create a result from a part of the result if it's too large, for example the first thousand records, and put a message above the result that it's truncated. Perhaps also a link to get the entire result, for example by adding a query string that you can check for.

Comment: I've been playing around with bits and chunks of data at a time using ajax.  Like getting 50k at a time and before I get another check see what the current size.  Maybe interrupting the user and saying would you like to stop the process or keep on going?

Comment: @RetroCoder: Yes, that would be a possibility, but then you get a lot of requests to the server, and you have to hang on to the result on the server side much longer than with a single request, so it depends in your situation if it's worth it. If you do this you should however send much larger chunks than 50k at a time, or you will get a lot of overhead.